# Funciones globales de Swift

Tags: swift

Bien, vengo leyendo y aprendiendo un poco sobre swift pero todavía no entiendo como es que puedo llamar a una función, sin tener un objeto o clase que la tenga.

Un ejemplo:

`print()` - Es una función que la puedo utilizar en cualquier parte del código . 
`abs()`- Sucede lo mismo.

Y hay muchas mas que no veo de donde salen...Igualmente, recién buscando por google, encontré [esto](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/#other). Una página donde me explican las funciones pero sigo sin entender de donde salen las funciones...si no tengo ningún objeto o clase creada, quien llame a esa función.

Segunda pregunta, conocen algún curso,video donde expliquen como utilizar adecuadamente la API de Swift?

Tercer y última pregunta, el operador `==` que compara exactamente?

Comment: Puedes definir tus funciones según se explica aquí: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html y como puedes ver no necesitas definir ninguna clase ni objeto para llamarla. Tu confusión sobre `==` puede venir sobre tus preguntas en Java donde `==` y `equals` tienen diferentes significados, pero en muchos lenguajes (casi todos) `==` y `equals` es lo mismo.

Comment: Osea me usa el protocolo 'comparable' cuando utilizó el operador == con objetos no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo debes distinguir entre funciones y métodos. Los primeros no son más que trozos de código con un objetivo concreto y/o retorno. Los segundos, no son más que funciones asociadas a un tipo particular de clase. O visto de otra forma, una función es un trozo de código y un método es ese mismo trozo metido dentro de una clase. Además, has de distinguir entre los métodos de clase y de instancia.
En el caso de `print()` y `abs()` por ejemplo, son funciones definidas en la biblioteca standard (como bien has puesto en tu enlace) que están definidas de forma global de manera que puede ser accedido des de cualquier lugar del código.

Sobre el operador `==` muy sencillo

- `=` operador de asignación
- `==` operador de igualdad
- `===` operador identidad

Para que te hagas una idea, con `=` asignas un valor, con `==` comparas valores, por ejemplo `a == b` y con el operador de identidad lo que comparas son las referencias de memoria de esos objetos para saber si son la misma instancia.

En el caso del operador de igualdad se comparan valores tales como `3 == 5` o `abc == bcd` pero si la clase implementa el protocolo de comparación, se puede utilizar para comparar lo que se necesite. Una buena explicación la puedes encontrar en: http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/

Comment: Con el operador de igualda que comparo?

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta

Comment: Genial, mil gracias